# How to get mouse wheel speed or mouse wheel notches moved in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, mousewheel

I know that **LibGDX** offers interfaces like `InputProcessor` and classes like `InputAdapter`.  They do have a scrolled method which can be override and be activated when the mouse wheel is moved.

It returns a `boolean` value and take an `integer` for the argument.  The integer will either be -1 or 1 depending on the mouse wheel's scrolling direction. -1 is up and 1 is down.

That's nice, but not fully what I need. I **need** to figure out the **mouse wheel's scrolling speed**. Java does have a `MouseWheelListener` that allows one to find out how many notches the wheel has spun. I tried implementing that into `LibGDX` and it just didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any example code you could post for how you tried to implement the MouseWheelListener?

Comment: I realized I was being foolish. I was trying to implement it like how you would implement it with a JFrame. Maybe I should try using something LWJGL has?  I don't know if LibGDX has overridden anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, there's most likely a way to attach a `MouseWheelListener` to a `LibGDX` window object

Comment: You need the speed, as in clicks per second?

Comment: I need to know how fast the mouse's wheel is spinning.

Comment: But the speed varies depending on the timeframe you look at. What are you really trying to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You can track the wheelattacks/second by counting the mousewheel-attacks via the scrolled() method in the inputprocessor and reset the timer at every call of the render() method. attacks*delta should give you the speed.